# Time limit while finding the duplicates in two lists

Tags: python

- First argument is an integer array A of size N.
- Second argument is an integer array B of size M.
- Return an integer array denoting the common elements.
- Input >  A = [1, 2, 2, 1],  B = [2, 3, 1, 2], out >  [1, 2, 2]
- Input > A = [2, 1, 4, 10],  B = [3, 6, 2, 10, 10], out >  [2, 10]

Code is below I got the proper out, but for higher number of elements i m getting errror

```
    def solve(A, B):
        result = []
        for element in A:
            if element in B:
                result.append(element)
                B.remove(element)
        return result
```

DO i need to do generator yield functionality for this

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @luke no error, time limit exceed error

Comment: @luke why you close the question, its not the same question if you read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Membership tests of a list with the `in` operator cost *O(n)* in time complexity. You can improve the efficiency by converting the list to a `collections.Counter` object first to improve the time complexity of membership lookups to *O(1)*:

```
from collections import Counter

def solve(A, B):
    B = Counter(B)
    result = []
    for element in A:
        if element in B:
            result.append(element)
            B -= {element: 1}
    return result
```

In fact, `collections.Counter` offers the intersection operator (`&`) just for this purpose:

```
def solve(A, B):
    return list((Counter(A) & Counter(B)).elements())
```

Comment: A : [ 1, 2, 2, 1 ]
B : [ 2, 3, 1, 2 ]  Expected out is [1 2 2 ]  your out is [1,2]

Comment: Oops did not realize that the items can repeat. Updated my answer then.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'int' and 'NoneType'

Comment: B -= {element: None}

Comment: one question its still o(n) complexity right since we are looping, I got time limit exceed error here also,if i am sending around million records

Comment: In this case do i need to write yield functionality

Comment: No I don't believe converting the function to a generator will improve performance in any way in this case. You can try using the built-in intersection operator of the 'Counter` class, however, which is implemented in a generally more efficient way. I've updated my answer with an example.